# How to Retrieve and Render Uniquely Selected Dropdown Values from the Database

Tags: php

In PHP I am doing a query for the current priority ($priority) and a dynamic list of priorities from the database. The problem I am trying to solve is how to only show values in the dropdown not currently selected. For instance, if the priority value in the database is 'low', when the while loop goes through to render dropdown options, 'low' is still in the drop down list even though it is already listed as being selected (appears as a duplicate in the list). From a UX perspective, I'd rather see the selected value and then the values not currently selected. Thank you for your help.

[image]

```
         <select class="form-control" id="priority" name="priority" id="priority">
            <option selected="<?php echo $query2['priority']; ?>. selected"><?php echo $query2['priority']; ?></option>
            <?php
              $priority = $query2['priority'];
              $query3=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT priority FROM todo ORDER BY priority ASC");

              while($listOfPrioritiesVal=mysqli_fetch_array($query3)){
                if ($priority == $listOfPrioritiesVal['priority']) {
                  echo "";
                }

                else {
                  echo '<option value="'.$listOfPrioritiesVal['priority'].'">'.$listOfPrioritiesVal['priority'].'</option>';
                }
              } 
            ?>
          </select>
```

Comment: Try this: <option selected="selected"><?php echo $query2['priority']; ?></option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a `<option>` tag for the selected value you could just continue the loop without doing anything.

```
while($listOfPrioritiesVal=mysqli_fetch_array($query3)){

    if ($priority === $listOfPrioritiesVal['priority']) {
        continue;
    }else{
        echo '<option value="'.$listOfPrioritiesVal['priority'].'">'.$listOfPrioritiesVal['priority'].'</option>';
    }
}
```

But i would suggest something like follows.

```
//  Remove your very first `<option>` tag.
while($listOfPrioritiesVal=mysqli_fetch_array($query3)){

    if ($priority === $listOfPrioritiesVal['priority']) {

        <option selected="selected"><?php echo $priority; ?></option>

    }else{

        echo '<option value="'.$listOfPrioritiesVal['priority'].'">'.$listOfPrioritiesVal['priority'].'</option>';
    }
}
```